# Why sometimes viewDidLoad is called first and sometimes it's called latter?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

```
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ListOrMapAddReloadButton object:self]; //Add nearby buttons
}
```

In one `UIViewController` here is the sequence

1. `viewDidload` get called
2. `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ListOrMapAddReloadButton object:self];`

And because the notification set up is called at viewDidLoad, I kind of need viewDidLoad to be called first before     `

1. `-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`

`

How could I achieve that?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(addReloadButton) name:ListOrMapAddReloadButton object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(addNearbyButton) name:ListOrMapAddNearbyButton object:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your notifications in ViewWillAppear ()

Comment: I want it to be called only once and then removed at dealloc. Hence I put it on viewdidload. I think viewdidload is a suitable "pair" for dealloc.

Comment: Well actually the most suitable "pair" for `dealloc` would be `init`…